# Cent OS 6.6 enable Plaintext authentication on dovecot and postfix

Tags: centos, postfix, authentication, dovecot

A customer of mine wants to use gmail as their default mail client but I have rolled forward to a new CENTOS server version (6.6, ok it's not `"new"` new) and the dovecot and postfix settings are default to be fairly hardened.

However though the centos server supports IMAP SSL out of the box, I cannot use that because gmail (as a client) only supports POP3 and with PLAINTEXT authentication.

**gmail said**

```
POP3 Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "Plaintext authentication disallowed on non-secure
(SSL/TLS) connections."
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) but the changes I made have not effect I still get that gmail error message. Port 110 is open.

As per the howto:

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf is set to

```
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
   mode = 0666
   user = postfix
   group = postfix
}
```

I added these lines to /etc/postfix.main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  permit_mynetworks
  reject_unauth_destination
```

extra info

```
 [root@somemail ~]# postconf -d | grep mail_version
 mail_version = 2.6.6
 milter_macro_v = $mail_name $mail_version
 [root@somemail ~]# dovecot --version
 2.0.9
 [root@somemail ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
 CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

but at the moment I still get the gmail warning, what else should I be doing to enable plaintext authentication?

Comment: I figured it out there needs to be the line `disable_plaintext_auth = no` in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
$ doveconf disable_plaintext_auth
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `disable_plaintext_auth = no` in the dovecot configuration file. Open `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` and add following line at the end of the file:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
```

Finally restart dovecot service by following command:

```
service dovecot restart
```